# Postback in Databound GridView ASP.NT VB

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

I have been given an 8 year old piece of software to update and it's proving tricky.  The project is ASP.NET written in VB.NET.  ASP is not my area of expertise, so I'm really struggling on some of the finer points.

The code lists parameters for a user to edit, and my task is to add and remove items from a drop-down and display them in a datagrid.  However, this part of the feature is half-written and appears to use a Modal Popup Extender to load a modal form, onto which are placed the controls.  The datagrid containing the already added items are DataBound from a list of classes.

All of the buttons, when clicked, perform their task and close the modal form.  Selecting a row in the DataGrid does the same (I used the AutogenerateSelectButton = True property to get the selection button), and I do NOT need this to happen.

After asking the original creator of this project (no longer an employee of my firm) he suggested that it could be doing a post-back.  After a morning's worth of research and trial/error, the general consensus is that I need to use an Update Panel?

Again, with ASP.NET not being my area of expertise, I have no idea how to cleanly go about this, assuming that this is the correct way to go.  Attached is the ASP code for the grid and a button.

```
<td colspan="3" rowspan="4">
     <asp:GridView ID="grdClientLinks" runat="server" AutoGenerateSelectButton="True" CellPadding="10" CellSpacing="10">
          <SelectedRowStyle BackColor="#0066FF" />
     </asp:GridView>
                                
</td>


<td colspan="2" class="auto-style8">
     <asp:Button ID="cmdCancelLink" runat="server" Text="Cancel" CausesValidation="False" />
</td>
```

Any assistance would be helpful if it could just make the gridview or buttons stop closing the forms.

Comment: The flow is user selects value from dropdown/combo, and then we pop a gridview of data based on that selection. (so far so good!). Now, pop dialog display gv, user then going to select a row (so far so good). Now, I assume after the user selects a row, or picked a row, we now close the popped up gv) and are now back to the page with all of the information, or at the very least the row information (or PK) of the selected row. The rather confusing part is why would you not want the GV to close after user selects the gv row? Why would the GV stay open? So MORE in this dialog then select occurs?

Answer (score 0):

As I asked for in comments, the question as to what is to occur in that pop dialog or modal form is a HUGE an BEYOND important question here.

In most cases, we will have a UI in which some data is displayed, (say a grid view), and then to edit each row, we pop that details dialog.

So, say like this:

[image]

So, above is a simple Gridview, and when we click on a button in the GV, then we pop that "modal dialog" to edit the one record. However, hitting any button in that dialog form WILL COLLOPSE the modal diag. However, as you can see in above, that is VERY good (desired) behavior, since any cancel, or save button click , we WANT the dialog form to close/collapse anyway! (so that closing and dismissing of the dialog occurs automatic due to the post back, and thus not ONE line of code is required for this to occur).

Now, it is also possible you want the "reverse"!. While I do not like this 2nd type of UI, it is somewhat common.

So, in that case, you "reverse" the above, and we display the edit form, but pop a dialog (a gridview) to allow the user to choose the hotel to work on.

So, my markup might display the hotel edit area, and I click a button to choose a hotel, and that hotel is a pop dialog with a grid view inside.

However, ONCE again, hitting a button in that dialog will close the dialog, and AGIAN that is a great/good thing we want to occur.

So, I drop in my edit hotel control, and below that I have a gridview.

this markup:

```
<div style="font-size: large; float: left">
    Edit Hotels
</div>
<asp:Button ID="cmdPickHotel" runat="server" 
    style="float:left;margin-left:15px;margin-top:-5px"
    Text="Choose Hotel"
    OnClientClick="popsel(this);return false"
    CssClass="btn myshadow" />

<br />
<br />

<hr style="height:1px;background:black" />

<uc1:MyEditHotelC runat="server" 
    ID="MyEditHotelC"
    MyTitle="Hotel Infomration"
    MyTable ="tblHotelsA"
    />

<div id="myhotelpop" style="display:none">
    <asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False"
        DataKeyNames="ID" CssClass="table table-hover"
        Width="60em" GridLines="None">
        <Columns>
            <asp:BoundField DataField="FirstName"   HeaderText="FirstName" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="LastName"    HeaderText="LastName" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="City"        HeaderText="City" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="HotelName"   HeaderText="HotelName" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="Description" HeaderText="Description" />
            <asp:TemplateField>
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <asp:Button ID="cmdSelect" runat="server" Text="Select" 
                        CssClass="btn myshadow"
                        OnClick="cmdSelect_Click" />
                </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateField>
        </Columns>
    </asp:GridView>
</div>
```

and right below above (since I don't have the ajax pop up extender installed, I will use the jquery.ui "dialog" - they both do much  the same things.

```
   <script>
       function popsel(btn) {

           var myDialog = $("#myhotelpop");
           myDialog.dialog({
               title: "Select Hotel",
               modal: true,
               appendTo: "form",
               dialogClass: "dialogWithDropShadow",
               width: "45%",    
               position: { my: "left top", at: "right bottom", of: btn },
                buttons: [
                    {
                        text: 'Cancel',
                        class: 'myshadow',
                        click: function () {
                            myDialog.dialog('close')
                        }
                    }
                ]
           });
       }
   </script>
```

Note how the Grid view is hidden, and thus we hit a button to pop the gridview. Note how the user can click a button on the GV, or hit cancel.

The code behind the button is rather simple. Note how I also IGNORED and did not bother trying ot use the gridview events (such as selected index or any grdiview events. You really don't need nor have to use such events. Just a simple button and then button click event for the gridview button will suffice.

So, our vb code so far is this:

```
Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load

    If Not IsPostBack Then

        GridView1.DataSource = Myrst("SELECT * FROM tblHotelsA
                                      ORDER BY HotelName")
        GridView1.DataBind()

    End If


End Sub


Protected Sub cmdSelect_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)

    ' user click in gridview row.
    Dim btn As Button = sender
    Dim gRow As GridViewRow = btn.NamingContainer
    Dim intPK As Integer = GridView1.DataKeys(gRow.RowIndex).Item("ID")

    ' Now load up our edit area based on database PK

    MyEditHotelC.MyPk = intPK
    MyEditHotelC.LoadData()

End Sub
```

So, on page load, we load up the grid (that we going to pop up). It is in a hidden div.

And above has the row click code for the row click. The result and effect is this:

[image]

Note again:

When we pop that grid, then any user selection (the select button), then that causes a post back, but we again don't care, since that post back hides the dialog automatic, and we thus already filled out the edit area from making that choice in the gridview.

So, I have posted 2 common workflows (design patterns) here.

it not clear which one you trying to acheive.

In above, I used the jQuery.UI dialog, and the above COULD consider and use the  popup extender. That popup extender is from the ajaxtoolkit, and was often used in asp.net, since then no real JavaScript skills are required.

So, I could post/consider using the popup extender from the ajax toolkit, but the results, the code approach outlined above will and should work.

Having stated all the above, THERE ARE cases in which you MAY WELL want the pop dialog to have/use/enjoy/survive a post-back, but UNTILL such time the UI and work flow you have REALLY, but REALLY requires the pop dialog to have use of post-backs and continue to be a dialog? You have to think really long and hard if that is the requirement. As above shows, keeping the dialog pop form open is in most cases should NOT require post-backs, but then again, you may well require this ability.

The 2 solutions WHEN you need post-backs AND ALSO to keep the dialog form open?

You make web method calls (ajax, and do not post back).

Or

You can adopt a update panel. Adopting a update panel again is often a great choice since in near all cases you don't then have to start writing a bunch of ajax and client side code to "eliminate" this need for post-backs.